# SPI command versus data?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, spi

I have bough an LCD screen display TFT Touch Screen Board For Arduino UNO R3.

Aand the following commands are given to me for the initialization:

```
write_SPI_commond(0xFF);
write_SPI_commond(0xFF);
delay_nms(5);
write_SPI_commond(0xFF);
write_SPI_commond(0xFF);
write_SPI_commond(0xFF);
write_SPI_commond(0xFF);
delay_nms(10);

write_SPI_commond(0xB0);
write_SPI_data(0x00);

write_SPI_commond(0xB3);
write_SPI_data(0x02);
write_SPI_data(0x00);
write_SPI_data(0x00);
write_SPI_data(0x10);

write_SPI_commond(0xB4);
write_SPI_data(0x11);//0X10

write_SPI_commond(0xC0);
write_SPI_data(0x13);
write_SPI_data(0x3B);//
write_SPI_data(0x00);
write_SPI_data(0x00);
write_SPI_data(0x00);
write_SPI_data(0x01);
write_SPI_data(0x00);//NW
write_SPI_data(0x43);

write_SPI_commond(0xC1);
write_SPI_data(0x08);
write_SPI_data(0x15);//CLOCK
write_SPI_data(0x08);
write_SPI_data(0x08);

write_SPI_commond(0xC4);
write_SPI_data(0x15);
write_SPI_data(0x03);
write_SPI_data(0x03);
write_SPI_data(0x01);

write_SPI_commond(0xC6);
write_SPI_data(0x02);

write_SPI_commond(0xC8);
write_SPI_data(0x0c);
write_SPI_data(0x05);
write_SPI_data(0x0A);//0X12
write_SPI_data(0x6B);//0x7D
write_SPI_data(0x04);
write_SPI_data(0x06);//0x08
write_SPI_data(0x15);//0x0A
write_SPI_data(0x10);
write_SPI_data(0x00);
write_SPI_data(0x31);//0x23

write_SPI_data(0x10);
write_SPI_data(0x15);//0x0A
write_SPI_data(0x06);//0x08
write_SPI_data(0x64);//0x74
write_SPI_data(0x0D);//0x0B
write_SPI_data(0x0A);//0x12
write_SPI_data(0x05);//0x08
write_SPI_data(0x0C);//0x06
write_SPI_data(0x31);//0x23
write_SPI_data(0x00);

write_SPI_commond(0x35);
write_SPI_data(0x00);

//write_SPI_commond(0x36);
//write_SPI_data(0x00);

write_SPI_commond(0x0C);
write_SPI_data(0x66);

write_SPI_commond(0x3A);
write_SPI_data(0x66);

write_SPI_commond(0x44);
write_SPI_data(0x00);
write_SPI_data(0x01);

write_SPI_commond(0xD0);
write_SPI_data(0x07);
write_SPI_data(0x07);//VCI1
write_SPI_data(0x14);//VRH 0x1D
write_SPI_data(0xA2);//BT 0x06

write_SPI_commond(0xD1);
write_SPI_data(0x03);
write_SPI_data(0x5A);//VCM  0x5A
write_SPI_data(0x10);//VDV

write_SPI_commond(0xD2);
write_SPI_data(0x03);
write_SPI_data(0x04);//0x24
write_SPI_data(0x04);

write_SPI_commond(0x11);
delay_nms(150);

write_SPI_commond(0x2A);
write_SPI_data(0x00);
write_SPI_data(0x00);
write_SPI_data(0x01);
write_SPI_data(0x3F);//320

write_SPI_commond(0x2B);
write_SPI_data(0x00);
write_SPI_data(0x00);
write_SPI_data(0x01);
write_SPI_data(0xDF);//480

//write_SPI_commond(0xB4);
//write_SPI_data(0x00);
delay_nms(100);

write_SPI_commond(0x29);
delay_nms(30);

write_SPI_commond(0x2C);
```

These commands do not look like Arduino commands to me. I have placed them like this

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Test!");

    SPI.begin();

    write_SPI_commond(0xFF);
    write_SPI_commond(0xFF);
    delay_nms(5);
    write_SPI_commond(0xFF);
    write_SPI_commond(0xFF);
    write_SPI_commond(0xFF);
    write_SPI_commond(0xFF);
    delay_nms(10);

    write_SPI_commond(0xB0);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);

    write_SPI_commond(0xB3);
    write_SPI_data(0x02);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);
    write_SPI_data(0x10);

    write_SPI_commond(0xB4);
    write_SPI_data(0x11);//0X10

    write_SPI_commond(0xC0);
    write_SPI_data(0x13);
    write_SPI_data(0x3B);//
    write_SPI_data(0x00);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);
    write_SPI_data(0x01);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);//NW
    write_SPI_data(0x43);

    write_SPI_commond(0xC1);
    write_SPI_data(0x08);
    write_SPI_data(0x15);//CLOCK
    write_SPI_data(0x08);
    write_SPI_data(0x08);

    write_SPI_commond(0xC4);
    write_SPI_data(0x15);
    write_SPI_data(0x03);
    write_SPI_data(0x03);
    write_SPI_data(0x01);

    write_SPI_commond(0xC6);
    write_SPI_data(0x02);

    write_SPI_commond(0xC8);
    write_SPI_data(0x0c);
    write_SPI_data(0x05);
    write_SPI_data(0x0A);//0X12
    write_SPI_data(0x6B);//0x7D
    write_SPI_data(0x04);
    write_SPI_data(0x06);//0x08
    write_SPI_data(0x15);//0x0A
    write_SPI_data(0x10);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);
    write_SPI_data(0x31);//0x23

    write_SPI_data(0x10);
    write_SPI_data(0x15);//0x0A
    write_SPI_data(0x06);//0x08
    write_SPI_data(0x64);//0x74
    write_SPI_data(0x0D);//0x0B
    write_SPI_data(0x0A);//0x12
    write_SPI_data(0x05);//0x08
    write_SPI_data(0x0C);//0x06
    write_SPI_data(0x31);//0x23
    write_SPI_data(0x00);

    write_SPI_commond(0x35);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);

    //write_SPI_commond(0x36);
    //write_SPI_data(0x00);

    write_SPI_commond(0x0C);
    write_SPI_data(0x66);

    write_SPI_commond(0x3A);
    write_SPI_data(0x66);

    write_SPI_commond(0x44);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);
    write_SPI_data(0x01);

    write_SPI_commond(0xD0);
    write_SPI_data(0x07);
    write_SPI_data(0x07);//VCI1
    write_SPI_data(0x14);//VRH 0x1D
    write_SPI_data(0xA2);//BT 0x06

    write_SPI_commond(0xD1);
    write_SPI_data(0x03);
    write_SPI_data(0x5A);//VCM  0x5A
    write_SPI_data(0x10);//VDV

    write_SPI_commond(0xD2);
    write_SPI_data(0x03);
    write_SPI_data(0x04);//0x24
    write_SPI_data(0x04);

    write_SPI_commond(0x11);
    delay_nms(150);

    write_SPI_commond(0x2A);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);
    write_SPI_data(0x01);
    write_SPI_data(0x3F);//320

    write_SPI_commond(0x2B);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);
    write_SPI_data(0x00);
    write_SPI_data(0x01);
    write_SPI_data(0xDF);//480

    //write_SPI_commond(0xB4);
    //write_SPI_data(0x00);
    delay_nms(100);

    write_SPI_commond(0x29);
    delay_nms(30);

    write_SPI_commond(0x2C);
}


void loop(void)
{
    delay(1000);
}
```

and I get many errors like

```
error: ‘write_SPI_commond’ was not declared in this scope
```

Even fixing the typo to `write_SPI_command` does not work. I have no problem with using the default `SPI.transfer` of the Arduino library. But, I am wondering how to translate `write_SPI_commond` and `write_SPI_data` into a proper `SPI.transfer`?

Comment: What do you mean by “_the following commands are given to me_”? Given by whom? Is that a documentation accessible on the Web? If so, please provide the link.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, By the [vendor](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/3-5-inch-TFT-LCD-Touch-Screen-Module-480x320-For-arduino-mega2560-board-AU-/163036335745). Under "Initialization Code".

Answer (score 2):

The “commands” provided by the vendor are not code meant to be copied
as-is. They are [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode). If you need to know the real difference
between “write command” and “write data”, you have to look at the
datasheet of the interface chip.

See for example the [ILI9481](https://www.crystalfontz.com/controllers/Ilitek/ILI9481/144/). On pages 28–29 you can see a data
transfer mode compatible with SPI (type C interface, option 3). Here you
have to wire one digital output of the Arduino to the D/CX pin on the
interface chip. This pin is used to tell whether you are writing a
command (pin LOW) or data (pin HIGH).

Comment: It is very cryptic. Can you please explain the data and command in a clear language?

Comment: @ar2015: No, I only know what I saw by looking at the datasheet. A careful read would be needed for fully understanding the protocol. I could do it. So can you.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title "**SPI command versus data?**":

### TLDR

Some SPI drivers will separate the data sent on the [COPI/PICO](https://www.sparkfun.com/spi_signal_names?_ga=2.24794995.891517377.1639774114-1543916381.1637822354) lines into subsections to make it easier on the programmer.

### SPI command versus data?

I am currently working with the ESP32 myself and have come accross the more generic question of "**What is the difference between command and data when using SPI?**". After some reading around, I have come to the conclusion that certain SPI drivers will allow users to separate the generic data sent in SPI protocal into subsections such as ADDRESS, COMMAND, and ADDITIONAL_DATA. This is simply to make it easier for the programmer to understand what they are sending.

Not all applications will require the an ADDRESS, COMMAND, and ADDITIONAL_DATA. For example, some chips will have pre-programmed commands such as this [Inclinometer (SCA61T)](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/tn15_spi_interface_specification.PDF) which then may or may not require ADDRESS and ADDITIONAL_DATA. But others, such as the [MAX7219](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX7219_MAX7221-1513157.pdf) (which I am using), only require an ADDRESS and ADDITIONAL_DATA, no COMMAND.

### Example

Using the ESP32 SPI driver, I played around with setting the length of the command bits and address bits from 0 to some nonzero number as seen in the code snippet below.

```
spi_device_interface_config_t devcfg={
                .command_bits=4,           ///< Default amount of bits in command phase (0-16), used when ``SPI_TRANS_VARIABLE_CMD`` is not used, otherwise ignored.
                .address_bits=4            ///< Default amount of bits in address phase (0-64), used when ``SPI_TRANS_VARIABLE_ADDR`` is not used, otherwise ignored.    
}
```

Then I specified the data to be sent in the command and address bits (along with the data to be sent in the tx buffer) as seen in the code below.

```
     char data[1]= {0x97};
            
            spi_transaction_t spi_trans={
                .cmd={0x05},          ///< Command data, of which the length is set in the ``command_bits`` of spi_device_interface_config_t.
                .addr={0x00},         ///< Address data, of which the length is set in the ``address_bits`` of spi_device_interface_config_t.
                .length=8,            ///< Total data length, in bits
                .rxlength=0,          ///< Total data length received, should be not greater than ``length`` in full-duplex mode (0 defaults this to the value of ``length``).
                .rx_buffer=data,      ///< Pointer to receive buffer, or NULL for no MISO phase. Written by 4 bytes-unit if DMA is used.
                .tx_buffer=data,      ///< Pointer to transmit buffer, or NULL for no MOSI phase

            };
```

where `spi_trans.cmd = {0x05}` with 4 bits length corresponds to a binary `0101`, `spi_trans.addr = {0x00}` with 4 bits length corresponds to a binary `0000`, and `spi_trans.tx_buffer = {0x97}` with 8 bits length corresponds to a binary `10010111`.

When using an o-scope to measure the chosen COPI and clock pins, we see the following waveform.

[image]

We realize the ordering of the data sent over the COPI pin is command, then address, and lastly tx data. This ordering may differ depending on which driver is used (I am using the [ESP32 SPI Master driver](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/spi_master.html)).